# k subsets of a set

Tags: combinatorics

> Given a set of n elements, find the maximum number of ordered k-tuples possible such that every pair of k-tuples has at least one element in common.

For example, if $n=3$ and $k=2$, the set of ordered 2-tuples is: $\{(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,2),(3,1),(2,1)\}$
Here every pair of tuples has at least one common element, hence answer is 6.

**Note**: $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ are different tuples.

Comment: By pairs, do you mean "ordered k-tuple"?

Comment: You can convert this to the "unordered" version by just dividing out by $k!$. There is a 'bijective' map from the $k!$ ordered tuples to the set.

Comment: @calvin: Yes i mean ordered pairs

Comment: What if $ k \neq 2$? The word "pairs" strongly suggests only 2 elements.

Comment: It is specified that pair should have k elements..so k can be anything ,more specifically 0<k<=n

Comment: Alright, I will take it that you're abusing notation, and that pairs means "ordered k-tuple".

Comment: sorry for this, i will take care next time

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that for $n = 4$ and $k=2$, the answer is $6$ as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Calvin Lin observed, for every subset of size $k$, there are $k!$ k-tuples. So I'll focus on those subsets first. We'll just have to multiply our answer by $k!$ afterwards.

There are two distinct cases, depending on whether $k$ is greater than $\frac{n}{2}$.
This is because if $k > \frac{n}{2}$, for any given subset of size $k$, it's *impossible* to construct a second subset of that same size that doesn't contain at least one element of the first subset.
This means the answer for these cases is equal to the total number of subsets, which is $n \choose k$.

Now if $k \le \frac{n}{2}$, *I think* we need to choose one element to be in all subsets, or it would be possible to construct a second, *disjoint* subset. So after having picked 1 such element, there are ${n-1}\choose{k-1}$ subsets that can be created containing that element.

So, remembering that we have to multiply by $k!$, the maximum number $m$ of ordered k-tuples is
$$
m(n,k)=\cases {
\begin{align}
{{n}\choose{k}} \cdot & k! & \text{if } k > \tfrac{n}{2}\cr \\
{{n-1}\choose{k-1}} \cdot & k! & \text{if } k \le \tfrac{n}{2}
\end{align}}
$$

Comment: nice and simple explanation thank you:)

Comment: @SQB: Your answer comes by extending [Erdos-ko-rado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem) theorem under the assumption that every [tuple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Properties) has $k$ different elements. Considering that a $k$-tuple may have not more than $k$ elements, the situation can be a little more involved.

Comment: @talegari From the description given, I assumed tuples of exactly k different elements.

Answer (score 0):

We are counting the maximum size of a family of ordered $k$-tuples of $[n]:=\{1,2,\dots ,n\}$ such that any two $k$-tuples have a common element, where $1\le k\le n$.

**Candidate(1)**: We **suspect that a** maximum family is obtained by keeping a element common between all the $k$-tuples (as we do with Erdos-ko-rado when the size the subsets is greater then $\frac{n}{2}$).

Let $1$ be the common element, wlog. We build a $k$-tuple using a $r$-subset of $[n]$ where $1\le r\le k$. Using inclusion-exclusion, we can build a $k$-tuple in $T(r,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}(-1)^{i}\binom{r}{i}(r-i)^k$ ways. Hence, the maximum size of the family of ordered $k$-tuples is $\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\binom{n-1}{r}T(r,k)$

**Candidate(2)** for maximum size when $k>\frac{n}{2}$ is: $\binom{n}{k}k!$. The idea is to select two different $k$-subsets (they will intersect as $k>\frac{n}{2}$) and then generate all the $k$-tuples. Some experimentation with smaller numbers show that as $n$ grows candidate(1) is larger than candidate(2) even when $k>\frac{n}{2}$. Although, for $n=3,k=2$, candidate(2) gives the correct answer.